# Why do they say that in the Proto-type Pattern - be used to simply duplicate the original object whenever a new one is needed?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to learn the design pattern. I am a C++ programmer. Currently, I am juggling with the Proto-type pattern. I could co-relate Prototype with the factory type. However, there are a lot of differences between factory and prototype pattern. For example, in the prototype pattern each derived class registers its prototype with the base/super class.

However, looking at the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern) - I couldn't understood the following points.

1. Rather than retrieving the data and re-parsing it each time a new object is created, the prototype pattern can be used to simply duplicate the original object whenever a new one is needed.
2. avoid the inherent cost of creating a new object in the standard way (e.g., using the 'new' keyword) when it is prohibitively expensive for a given application.

Here is the program, I created to demonstrate the prototype pattern in C++. However, I cannot find any benefit out of it. How come a prototype pattern will help in quickly creating the object here. I can see that the object has to call 'new' every time. Here is the entire program, please correct me if you think that I haven't implemented the prototype pattern correctly.

Sorry for the long program - but trust me it is quite simple.

Like a factory object - here is the prototype class

```
 -- basically an abstract.

class Itransport
{

public:

enum transportPacketType
 {
   udp,
   tcp,
   MAX
 };

private:
     static std::list<Itransport *> prototypesList;

protected:
     virtual Itransport::transportPacketType getPacketType() = 0;
     virtual Itransport* clone() = 0;

     /** This will be called by the derived classes **/
     static void  registertoPrototypeList(Itransport *packet)
     {
        prototypesList.push_back(packet);
     }
public:

     virtual void showMessage() = 0;

 static Itransport* makeClone(Itransport::transportPacketType packType)
     {
        std::list<Itransport *>::iterator it;

        for(it = prototypesList.begin(); it != prototypesList.end(); it++)
           {
              if( (*it)->getPacketType() == packType )
                 {
                    return (*it)->clone();
                 }
           }
     }

     virtual ~Itransport() = 0;
};

Itransport::~Itransport()
{
   std::cout<<"Itransport Destructor called"<<std::endl;
}

std::list<Itransport *> Itransport::prototypesList;
```

Here is the concrete type of the Itransport Packet -

```
class udpPacket: public Itransport
{

private:

  static udpPacket udpTransportPacket;

protected:
Itransport::transportPacketType getPacketType()
{
   return  Itransport::udp;
}

Itransport* clone()
      {
           return new udpPacket();
      }

public:

void showMessage()
{
   std::cout<<"This is a UDP Packet"<<std::endl;
}

udpPacket()
{
   std::cout<<"UDP Packet Constructed"<<std::endl;
   registertoPrototypeList(this);
}

~udpPacket()
{
   std::cout<<"Destructor of udp called"<<std::endl;
}

};

static udpPacket udpTransportPacket;
```

Here is the client -

```
int main()
{
   Itransport *udpPacket;
   Itransport *udpPacket2;
   udpPacket = Itransport::makeClone(Itransport::udp);
   udpPacket->showMessage();

   udpPacket2 = Itransport::makeClone(Itransport::udp);
   udpPacket2->showMessage();

   delete udpPacket;
   delete udpPacket2;

   return 0;
}
```

I couldn't find any benefits related to 'new' here. Please throw some light on it.

Comment: Instead of `return new udpPacket();` it should probably be `return new udpPacket(*this);` because you want to create a copy of the prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can have a go at explaining the first point:

> Rather than retrieving the data and re-parsing it each time a new
>   object is created, the prototype pattern can be used to simply
>   duplicate the original object whenever a new one is needed.

Imagine a computer game that has to create a lot of monsters. Say all the different types of monster are not known at compile time but you construct a monster of a particular type from some input data that provides information about what color the monster is, etc:

```
class Monster {
 public:
  Monster(InputDataHandle handle) {
    // Retrieve input data...
    // Parse input data...
  }
  void setPosition(Position);
};
```

Then every time you want to construct, say a red monster you have to retrieve the data and re-parse:

```
// Spawn a lot of red monsters
for (int i = 0; i != large_number; ++i) {
    auto red = new Monster(red_monster_data); // Must retrieve data and re-parse!
    red->setPosition(getRandomPosition());
    game.add(red);
}
```

Clearly that is inefficient. One way of solving it is using the Prototype Pattern. You create one "prototype" red monster and every time you want to create an instance of a red monster you simply copy the prototype and you don't have to retrieve and re-parse the input data:

```
auto prototype_red_monster = new Monster(red_monster_data);

for (int i = 0; i != large_number; ++i) {
    auto red = prototype_red_monster->clone();
    red->setPosition(getRandomPosition());
    game.add(red);
}
```

But how is the clone function implemented? This brings us to the second point which I don't really understand:

> avoid the inherent cost of creating a new object in the standard way
>   (e.g., using the 'new' keyword) when it is prohibitively expensive for
>   a given application.

The clone function fundamentally has to allocate memory for the new object and copy data in from itself. I'm not sure I know what they are referring to when they talk about the "inherent cost of the `new` keyword". The examples are in Java and C# which have `clone()` and `MemberwiseClone()` respectively. In those languages you don't need to call `new`. I don't know how `clone()` and `MemberwiseClone()` are implemented but I don't see how they can "avoid the inherent cost of the `new` keyword".

In C++ we have to implement `clone()` ourselves and it will typically use `new` and use the copy constructor:

```
Monster* clone() {
  return new Monster(*this);
}
```

In this case the copy constructor is much cheaper than creating the object from scratch.  In your case it might not be.

The fact you cannot find any benefit from the Prototype Pattern in your case might mean it is the wrong pattern for your case and you will be better off with a different pattern like the [Object Pool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern), [Flyweight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) or [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) Pattern.

Comment: I liked your answer, but it clearly shows me that there is no benefit of prototype pattern in C++. The clone() in Java is a way different from the new operator.

Comment: I wouldn't agree that there is no benefit of prototype pattern in C++.  Clearly there are benefits in the example I provided.  And there are many other cases where it is useful. It just might not be useful in your case.